# Migration from Core 1.1 to 2.0 - Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-core-1.1, .net-core-2.0

In my .net core 1.1 code I'm doing the authentication as follows(which is sending the bearer token to external URL and look for claims in the return token). This code is in `Configure` method

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",

            Authority = signinAuthority,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = signinHTTPS,

            ClientId = "skybus",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = { "api1", "offline_access" },

            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            SaveTokens = true
        });
```

Now I upgraded my code to .net Core 2.0 the both `UseCookieAuthentication` & `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` are changed. I'm finding it difficult to find what needs to be done in this case

What I changed it to is as follows in `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
            {
                o.Authority = signinAuthority;
                o.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = signinHTTPS;
                o.ClientId = "skybus";
                o.ClientSecret = "secret";
                o.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                o.SaveTokens = true;
                o.Scope.Add("api1");
                o.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });
```

In Browser I see this URL after the above changes. It should either show me the external login page if user is not logged in or return to home page of my website

> http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed [this link from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to start my migration. Most of the migration is covered by the this link, but I faced issue where most of my claims are missing.

With the ASP.NET Core 1.x, client would have received the claims: nbf, exp, iss, aud, nonce, iat, c_hash, sid, sub, auth_time, idp, amr.

In Core 2.0 we only get sid, sub and idp. What happened?

Microsoft added a new concept to their OpenID Connect handler called ClaimActions. Claim actions allow modifying how claims from an external provider are mapped (or not) to a claim in your ClaimsPrincipal. Looking at the ctor of the OpenIdConnectOptions, you can see that the handler will now skip the following claims by default:

```
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("nonce");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("aud");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("azp");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("acr");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("amr");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("iss");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("iat");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("nbf");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("exp");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("at_hash");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("c_hash");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("auth_time");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("ipaddr");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("platf");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("ver");
```

If you want to “un-skip” a claim, you need to delete a specific claim action when setting up the handler. The following is the very intuitive syntax to get the amr claim back:

```
options.ClaimActions.Remove("amr");
```

**Requesting more claims from the OIDC provider**

When you are requesting more scopes, e.g. profile or custom scopes that result in more claims, there is another confusing detail to be aware of.

Depending on the response_type in the OIDC protocol, some claims are transferred via the id_token and some via the userinfo endpoint.

So first of all, you need to enable support for the userinfo endpoint in the handler:

```
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
```

In the end you need to add the following class to import all other custom claims

```
public class MapAllClaimsAction : ClaimAction
    {
        public MapAllClaimsAction() : base(string.Empty, string.Empty)
        {
        }

        public override void Run(JObject userData, ClaimsIdentity identity, string issuer)
        {
            foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
            {
                // If this claimType is mapped by the JwtSeurityTokenHandler, then this property will be set
                var shortClaimTypeName = claim.Properties.ContainsKey(JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ShortClaimTypeProperty) ?
                    claim.Properties[JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ShortClaimTypeProperty] : string.Empty;

                // checking if claim in the identity (generated from id_token) has the same type as a claim retrieved from userinfo endpoint
                JToken value;
                var isClaimIncluded = userData.TryGetValue(claim.Type, out value) || userData.TryGetValue(shortClaimTypeName, out value);

                // if a same claim exists (matching both type and value) both in id_token identity and userinfo response, remove the json entry from the userinfo response
                if (isClaimIncluded && claim.Value.Equals(value.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    if (!userData.Remove(claim.Type))
                    {
                        userData.Remove(shortClaimTypeName);
                    }
                }
            }

            // adding remaining unique claims from userinfo endpoint to the identity
            foreach (var pair in userData)
            {
                JToken value;
                var claimValue = userData.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out value) ? value.ToString() : null;
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(pair.Key, claimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String, issuer));
            }
        }
    }
```

and then use the above class code to add it to `ClaimActions`

```
options.ClaimActions.Add(new MapAllClaimsAction());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using IdentityServer4 but they have provided some samples on github for ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Hope this helps you.

[Sample Project](https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples/blob/aspnetcore2/OIDC/src/AspNetCoreSecurity/Startup.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Did you take the authentication middleware into use?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
...
```